# How to make a matrix that only holds None values?

Tags: python, matrix

I have to write a function `empty_matrix` that must return a list of lists (a matrix)

**desired output:**

```
empty_matrix(3,4)
```

returns a list with three lists each of length four:

```
[[None,None,None,None],[None,None,None,None],[None,None,None,None]]
```

What should I change in my code below???

```
def empty_matrix(row,column):
first_col = []
for x in range(len(matrix)):
        sublist = matrix[x]
        for y in range(len(sublist)):
            first_col.append(matrix[x][y])
```

Comment: using numpy  np.full([3, 4], None)

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
def empty_matrix(row, column):
    return [[None for _ in range(row)] for _ in range(column)]
```

But to fix your code, you're using `len` on variables `matrix` and `sublist` that aren't defined, your indentation is off, try something like this if you don't want to use a list comprehension.

```
def empty_matrix(row, column):
    matrix = []
    for c in range(column):
        column = []
        for r in range(row):
            column.append(None)
        matrix.append(column)
    return matrix
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it.

Comment: What do you not get?